# Python decorator's wrapper as class looses self when applied to object method

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, python-decorators

The following python code shows two decorators: `@decorator` and `@broken_decorator`. The second one is broken as it looses the reference to `self`. In fact, to use a decorated method with `@broken_decorator` one should give the self object as first parameter, eg. writing `three.plus_(MyClass(4), 4)`, printing 4 + 4 = 8 even the object to which plus is applied is `three`.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Callable


def decorator(func: Callable[["MyClass", int], None]):
  def wrapper(my_class_self: "MyClass", y: int):
    func(my_class_self, y)
  return wrapper

def broken_decorator(func: Callable[["MyClass", int], None]):
  class Wrapper:
    def __call__(self: "Wrapper", my_class_self: "MyClass", y: int):
      func(my_class_self, y)
  return Wrapper()

@dataclass
class MyClass:
  x: int

  @decorator
  def plus(self: "MyClass", y: int) -> None:
    print(f"{self.x} + {y} = {self.x + y}")

  @broken_decorator
  def plus_(self: "MyClass", y: int) -> None:
    print(f"{self.x} + {y} = {self.x + y}")

three = MyClass(3)
three.plus(4) # 3 + 4 = 7

# with @broken_decorator
three.plus_(MyClass(4), 4) # 4 + 4 = 8, as self is the new object MyClass(4)
```

Specifically, the difference between the two decorators is in the returned wrapper, the first one returns a function the second a class equipped with the `__call__` method.

Is this behaviour correct?

Comment: As a side-note: The wrappers produced by your decorators should definitely `return` whatever the wrapped function returns. It doesn't matter here, where they're not returning anything useful (just the implicit `None`), but you definitely don't want to discard useful return values from whatever arbitrary function/method you happened to wrap.

Comment: Of course, your `class Wrapper` is not a descriptor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's correct. Plain functions implement [the descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), which is what allows them to implicitly bind `self` as part of the lookup-and-call process. Your class does not implement the descriptor protocol, so it doesn't get this benefit.

You could manually implement `__get__` on your class so it also implemented the descriptor protocol appropriately, but unless there's a *really* good reason to do so, you're usually better off using functions (possibly with persistent state tracked via closure state) since they get all this functionality for free by default (and it's implemented more efficiently than anything you can hand-write in Python to boot). The equivalent implementation even for something as simple as simulating method binding is tricky; you'd need to have `__get__` return an instance of a different class that knew both the function to call and the `self` to provide, you'd need to make sure `__get__` *didn't* do this when it received `None` for the instance (in that case it should return itself unmodified), etc. It's a royal pain, and unless you have a *strong* motivation to write a custom class for this purpose, closure-scoped functions cover 99% of desired use cases and involve far less rigmarole, so use them.